# Ubuntu install is not recognizing my other OS (Windows 8)

Tags: 12.10

I am new to Linux and am excited to get started.  However, I do not want to replace Windows 8, I would like to simply have two operating systems.  I am installing from a flash drive.  When I start my computer, I go into the BIOS, select SanDisk, select Install Ubuntu, and then it works.  It does not, however, recognize my other OS and just wants to replace everything.  Why is it doing this and how do I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem before with Windows XP Pro. At the time I was installing Linux Mint (which is basically Ubuntu) over it. However, this should work:

If you want to keep windows, go to GParted (which comes with the ubuntu live cd), and create a new ext4 partition.

In more detail:
1. Start gparted.
2. Shrink your windows partition.
3. Create a new ext4 partition in the unallocated space.
4. Remember the number for your new partition. (should be /dev/sda2; windows should be /dev/sda1).

To install on the new partition:
When you get to the 'disks' section, choose something else. 
Find the new partition, select, and set the mount-point to /.

I am going to be fair and warn you that Windows does not always react well to having its partition resized. I resized my Windows 10 partition, and it damaged the Windows boot loader, so I had to reinstall windows.

Good luck, and welcome to the world of Linux! ^_^